# Can I get the email template by email id via SFMC API (REST/SOAP)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, soap-api

I have a few emails in Email Studio (I don't have any classic emails). I would like to use the API (either SOAP or REST whichever works) to get the email template. Then after that, I will make another call to SFMC to get the data of a subscriber which is saved in a data extension and use this data to fill up the info in the email template.
I know how to retrieve data from a data extension using the API but I don't know how to get the email template using the API.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of something I've done before to retrieve the HTML of an email. I then combined the email code with data from a DE to create my own "preview" in a CloudPage. Adapt for your own use.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");

// Example of HTTP GET/POST to SFMC REST API to retrieve HTML of an email 
try {

    var authBaseUrl = 'https://YOURENDPOINT.auth.marketingcloudapis.com';
    var authEndPoint = '/v1/requestToken';
    var restBaseUrl = 'https://YOURENDPOINT.rest.marketingcloudapis.com';

    var emailID = '12345'
    var assetEndPoint = '/asset/v1/content/assets/' + emailID + '/channelviews/html';

    var authObj = {};
    authObj.clientId = 'YOURCLIENTID';
    authObj.clientSecret = 'YOURCLIENTSECRET';

    var contentType = 'application/json';

    var authReq = HTTP.Post(authBaseUrl + authEndPoint, contentType, Stringify(authObj));

    if (authReq.StatusCode == 200) {
        var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(authReq.Response[0]);
        var accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;

        if (accessToken) {
            var assetReq = HTTP.Get(restBaseUrl+assetEndPoint, ['Authorization'],['Bearer '+ accessToken]);

            // zero means success
            if (assetReq.Status == 0) {
                var assetContent = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(assetReq.Content);
                // html of email
                var emailHtml = assetContent.compiled;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // error handling
    }

} catch (ex) {
Write("An error has occurred: " + Stringify(ex));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Josh de Blank, thanks for your response. It was the answer I was looking for. Just one small comment. We need to use assetID instead of emailID.